# Why does the determinant $D$, have to be $0$ for equation to have a solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, systems-of-equations

Suppose $2\times2$ equation:

$$
  \begin{cases}
   a_1x + b_1y = c_1  \\
   a_2x + b_2y = c_2 
  \end{cases} $$

We can make determinants:

$$D=\begin{vmatrix}{a_1}&{b_1}\\{a_2}&{b_2}\end{vmatrix}$$

$$A=\begin{vmatrix}{a_1}&{c_1}\\{a_2}&{c_2}\end{vmatrix}$$

$$B=\begin{vmatrix}{c_1}&{b_1}\\{c_2}&{b_2}\end{vmatrix}$$

Solution to the $2\times2$ equation exists if $D = 0$

Why?

Comment: This is not true; consider any case with $a_1 = b_1 = 0$, $c_1 \neq 0$. Then, $D = 0$ but the system admits no solution because its first equation doesn't.

Comment: I think your *question* needs work before we can answer...

Answer (score 2):

Some intuitions.

From some point of view, your equation is $DX=B$, hence, if it is possible, $D^{-1}DX=X=D^{-1}B$ and  Cauchy's theorem about determinants  implies, that $\det D\neq 0$, because $D^{-1}D=I$.

Comment: But If $B=0$ the system has infinitely solutions.

Comment: This is incorrect imo: you are **assuming** $\;D^{-1}\;$ exists to begin with in your first line: obviously that then it *must be* that $\;\det D\neq 0\;$ . The fact is that a non-homogeneous square system still can have solution even if $\;\det D=0\;$ .

Comment: @Timbuc In fact, the question is about the Cramer method. Hence my "from some point of view" and the rest.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke, the answer's still incorrect. True, Cramer's Rule assumes the determinanto isn't zero, yet the OP didn't mention this and he asks why there's a solution if it is zero, which apparently shows some deep misunderstanding in what he does. Anyway, in your answer, again, you **assume** (a priori, without any further condition, which doesn't exist) that the  matrix is invertible, which doesn't address the OP's question, imo.

Answer (score 0):

No no, you got this the wrong way. If $ \det D \ne 0$ which is the "general" case then the system has a unique solution . If $\det D = 0$ which is the "specific" case further investigation is required and the system has either no solution or infinitely many solutions.

Answer (score -2):

Consider this linear system: 
\begin{equation}
\begin{matrix}
a_1x+b_1y&={c_1}\\ a_2x + b_2y&= {c_2}\end{matrix}
\end{equation}
which, in matrix format is
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix} a_1 & b_1 \\ a_2 & b_2 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} {c_1} \\ {c_2} \end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}
Solutions to which can be found with Cramer's rule, as
\begin{equation}
x = \begin{vmatrix} {{c_1}} & b_1 \\ c_2 & b_2 \end{vmatrix}/\begin{vmatrix} a_1 & b_1 \\ a_2 & b_2 \end{vmatrix}  = { c_1b_2 - b_1c_2 \over a_1b_2 - b_1a_2}
\end{equation}
Which shows that if the determinant is zero, there are no solutions. So in general this is not true.

Comment: This is not accurate.  It is possible for there to be solutions when the determinant is zero.  Consider the case where all $a_i$,$b_i$, and $c_i$ are zero.  Then any $x$ and $y$ are a solution.

Comment: Ok, so I'll make the case for non-zero coefficients. My point is now valid.

Comment: Not so.  If all $a_i$,$b_i$, and $c_i$ are $1$ then $x=y=\frac{1}{2}$ is a solution, but the determinant is zero.  The condition for existence of a solution is that $[c_1,c_2]$ is in the column space of the matrix.  If the determinant is non-zero, then the column space is everything, so you're guaranteed a solution, but you can still have a solution if the determinant is zero.